# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-4.x

I have implemented a simple application in Hibernate-4. This application retrieve the value from a table. But when I try to get the record with this

```
(Booking) session.get(Booking.class, 3740456);
```

it gives me exception

```
INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

So, to verify into the database regarding table and column name, I copy the query from the log statement and execute it. It gives me proper output.

I checked several questions & answers related to this question, but could able to derive the solution.

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@SHKG9072DB:5030:TMSD10G2</property>
        <property name="connection.username">ICTDEV$EDI_APP</property>
        <property name="connection.password">p2II9JLIaea06</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
        <property name = "hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation">true</property>  


        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="com.hibernate.demo.Booking"/> 

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Booking.java**

```
package com.hibernate.demo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="EDI_IN_BOOKING")
public class Booking {

    /**
    * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
    private int id;

    @Column(name="SITE_AN")
    private String site;


    @Column(name="EVENT_ID")
    private int eventId;

    @Column(name="EVENT_DETAIL_ID")
    private int eventDetailId;

    @Column(name="RECORD_SEQUENCE_ID")
    private int recordSequenceId;

    @Column(name="RECORD_TYPE_N")
    int recordType; 

    @Column(name="EDI_SENDER_AN")
    String sender;

    @Column(name="EDI_RECIPIENT_AN")
    String recipient;

    @Column(name="PARTNER_C")
    String partner;

    @Column(name="SENDER_SEQUENCE_AN")
    String senderSequence;




    public String getSite() {
        return site;
    }

    public void setSite(String site) {
        this.site = (site);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = (id);
    }

    public int getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(int eventId) {
        this.eventId = (eventId);
    }

    public int getEventDetailId() {
        return eventDetailId;
    }

    public void setEventDetailId(int eventDetailId) {
        this.eventDetailId = (eventDetailId);
    }

    public int getRecordSequenceId() {
        return recordSequenceId;
    }

    public void setRecordSequenceId(int recordSequenceId) {
        this.recordSequenceId = (recordSequenceId);
    }

    public int getRecordType() {
        return recordType;
    }

    public void setRecordType(int recordType) {
        this.recordType = (recordType);
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = (sender);
    }

    public String getRecipient() {
        return recipient;
    }

    public void setRecipient(String recipient) {
        this.recipient = (recipient);
    }

    public String getPartner() {
        return partner;
    }

    public void setPartner(String partner) {
        this.partner = (partner);
    }

    public String getSenderSequence() {
        return senderSequence;
    }

    public void setSenderSequence(String senderSequence) {
        this.senderSequence = (senderSequence);
    }



}
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.hibernate.demo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Trying to create a test connection with the database.");
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 

        session.beginTransaction();
        Booking booking = (Booking) session.get(Booking.class, 3740456);        
        System.out.println(booking.getEventDetailId());
    }

}
```

**Table description**

```
desc EDi_IN_BOOKING
ID                             NOT NULL NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
EVENT_ID                       NOT NULL NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
EVENT_DETAIL_ID                NOT NULL NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
RECORD_SEQUENCE_ID             NOT NULL NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
RECORD_TYPE_N                           NUMBER(1)                                                                                                                                                                                     
SITE_AN                                 VARCHAR2(10)                                                                                                                                                                                  
EDI_SENDER_AN                           VARCHAR2(35)                                                                                                                                                                                  
EDI_RECIPIENT_AN                        VARCHAR2(35)                                                                                                                                                                                  
PARTNER_C                               VARCHAR2(20)                                                                                                                                                                                  
SENDER_SEQUENCE_AN                      VARCHAR2(15)
```

**Query from log (this gives correct output)**

```
select
booking0_.id as id1_0_0_,
booking0_.EVENT_DETAIL_ID as EVENT_DETAIL_ID2_0_0_,
booking0_.EVENT_ID as EVENT_ID3_0_0_,
booking0_.PARTNER_C as PARTNER_C4_0_0_,
booking0_.EDI_RECIPIENT_AN as EDI_RECIPIENT_AN5_0_0_,
booking0_.RECORD_SEQUENCE_ID as RECORD_SEQUENCE_ID6_0_0_,
booking0_.RECORD_TYPE_N as RECORD_TYPE_N7_0_0_,
booking0_.EDI_SENDER_AN as EDI_SENDER_AN8_0_0_,
booking0_.SENDER_SEQUENCE_AN as SENDER_SEQUENCE_AN9_0_0_,
booking0_.site_an as site_an10_0_0_ 
from
EDI_IN_BOOKING booking0_ 
where
booking0_.id=3740456;
```

**exception**

```
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: 
select
    booking0_.id as id1_0_0_,
    booking0_.EVENT_DETAIL_ID as EVENT_DETAIL_ID2_0_0_,
    booking0_.EVENT_ID as EVENT_ID3_0_0_,
    booking0_.PARTNER_C as PARTNER_C4_0_0_,
    booking0_.EDI_RECIPIENT_AN as EDI_RECIPIENT_AN5_0_0_,
    booking0_.RECORD_SEQUENCE_ID as RECORD_SEQUENCE_ID6_0_0_,
    booking0_.RECORD_TYPE_N as RECORD_TYPE_N7_0_0_,
    booking0_.EDI_SENDER_AN as EDI_SENDER_AN8_0_0_,
    booking0_.SENDER_SEQUENCE_AN as SENDER_SEQUENCE_AN9_0_0_,
    booking0_.site_an as site_an10_0_0_ 
from
    EDI_IN_BOOKING booking0_ 
where
    booking0_.id=?
 May 22, 2015 10:49:43 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
 WARN: SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
 May 22, 2015 10:49:43 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
 ERROR: ORA-00904: "BOOKING0_"."SITE_AN": invalid identifier

 May 22, 2015 10:49:43 AM org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener onLoad
 INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2587)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:991)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
at $Proxy7.get(Unknown Source)
at com.dpworld.demo.Main.main(Main.java:23)
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "BOOKING0_"."SITE_AN": invalid identifier

at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:589)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1957)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteDescribe(TTC7Protocol.java:850)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteQuery(OracleStatement.java:2555)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:2896)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:644)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:570)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
... 22 more
```

Comment: in your `Booking.java` you have mapped only one column do you have only one column in DB ?

Comment: there are other columns as well, it gives this exception for every column. But one column at a time in stack trace.

Comment: Map every column in DB with your `Booking ,java`

Comment: This is id column value I pass, it is primary key

Comment: try using session.load(Booking.class,3740456)

Answer (score 0):

Is your database configured with case sensitive columns? That could be one reason why Oracle is throwing an "invalid identifier" error
Check your table creating script.

Comment: Then it should also give me the same error when I execute the same query copied from log into SQL developer, That works fine..

Comment: Did you paste the code for Booking.java incorrectly? Why do I see 2 entities with one Table name "BOOKING" and the other "EDI_IN_BOOKING"?

Comment: The code is fine. Something is wrong with your configuration. Are you going against the right schema? instance? Can you recheck your connection info when you run the raw SQL vs the one configured in your hibernate config?

Answer (score 0):

Why is site_an in lowercase in the select such as booking0_.site_an as site_an10_0_0_ while all other column names are in uppercase. I think it may be an uppercase "i" issue.

```
select
booking0_.id as id1_0_0_,
booking0_.EVENT_DETAIL_ID as EVENT_DETAIL_ID2_0_0_,
booking0_.EVENT_ID as EVENT_ID3_0_0_,
booking0_.PARTNER_C as PARTNER_C4_0_0_,
booking0_.EDI_RECIPIENT_AN as EDI_RECIPIENT_AN5_0_0_,
booking0_.RECORD_SEQUENCE_ID as RECORD_SEQUENCE_ID6_0_0_,
booking0_.RECORD_TYPE_N as RECORD_TYPE_N7_0_0_,
booking0_.EDI_SENDER_AN as EDI_SENDER_AN8_0_0_,
booking0_.SENDER_SEQUENCE_AN as SENDER_SEQUENCE_AN9_0_0_,
booking0_.site_an as site_an10_0_0_
```

Comment: More interesting question: why is a five-year question rendered at the top of interesting questions? I just realized it was five-years old :)